# Returning a random text field input

Tags: java, netbeans-7.3

i'm pretty new to coding and i'm trying to make a program in java using NetBeans 7.3 (not sure if it really matters but better safe then sorry) to take the input from one text field that the user can put anything in and have a button to return the result into another text field. I have a total of 10 text fields (can and will lower if it makes things to complicated) and 3 buttons one to clear the text fields (already working) and one to exit (working) and the last one to get a random result which is what i'm having trouble with. Searching around for a while only lead to getting random numbers. So is it possible to grab a random result using the user entered text or is it easier to just label each text field with a number then have it recall a random number instead? i'm open to suggestions and improvements! Sorry for the confusion but this should clarify things. I'm trying to get the button "Random Choice will appear at the top" to take one of the jTextFields and transfer the user input text into jTextField11. Here is an image of the GUI http://oi50.tinypic.com/2a5aud4.jpg Here is the code i have already

```
*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package my.michelleschoices;

/**
*
* @author Antonio
*/
public class Michelleschoices extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Michelleschoices
 */
public Michelleschoices() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField9 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField10 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField11 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Michelle's Choices", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 0, 18))); // NOI18N

    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

    jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");

    jTextField3.setText("jTextField3");

    jTextField4.setText("jTextField4");

    jTextField5.setText("jTextField5");

    jTextField6.setText("jTextField6");

    jTextField7.setText("jTextField7");

    jTextField8.setText("jTextField8");

    jTextField9.setText("jTextField9");

    jTextField10.setText("jTextField10");

    jButton1.setText("Clear out all the choices");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Random choice will appear at the top");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 176, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3)
                        .addComponent(jTextField4)
                        .addComponent(jTextField5)
                        .addComponent(jTextField6))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2)
                        .addComponent(jTextField10)
                        .addComponent(jTextField9)
                        .addComponent(jTextField8)
                        .addComponent(jTextField7)))
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 358, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1))
    );

    jButton3.setText("Exit");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField11.setText("jTextField11");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jTextField11)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addComponent(jTextField11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.exit(0);
}                                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTextField1.setText("");
    jTextField2.setText("");
    jTextField3.setText("");
    jTextField4.setText("");
    jTextField5.setText("");
    jTextField6.setText("");
    jTextField7.setText("");
    jTextField8.setText("");
    jTextField9.setText("");
    jTextField10.setText("");
    jTextField11.setText("");
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Michelleschoices.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Michelleschoices.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Michelleschoices.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Michelleschoices.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Michelleschoices().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField10;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField11;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField8;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField9;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: I bet you will have a better chance to get the response you want if you can parse down ALL that code into just the relevant snippets. Good luck!

Comment: So what is your problem with the third button?

Comment: If I understood your question, you're having multiple text fields entering value and submitting it will transfer the values to next text field and goes on. And then there's this requirement to return a value randomly from one such text field. If that is the case, associate your text fields with an identifier. Obtain a Random number in the range of these identifiers and get its equivalent value.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number but should be in a range of the number of text fields.

Now switch the value generated (I have not used default in my switch as i know that case won't happen ever) and assign the value of text field as per the random number.

[image]

**EDIT :(This is what you are looking for)**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Michelleschoices extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Michelleschoices
 */
public Michelleschoices() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField9 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField10 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField11 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Michelle's Choices", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 0, 18))); // NOI18N

    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

    jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");

    jTextField3.setText("jTextField3");

    jTextField4.setText("jTextField4");

    jTextField5.setText("jTextField5");

    jTextField6.setText("jTextField6");

    jTextField7.setText("jTextField7");

    jTextField8.setText("jTextField8");

    jTextField9.setText("jTextField9");

    jTextField10.setText("jTextField10");

    jButton1.setText("Clear out all the choices");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Random choice will appear at the top");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 176, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3)
                        .addComponent(jTextField4)
                        .addComponent(jTextField5)
                        .addComponent(jTextField6))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2)
                        .addComponent(jTextField10)
                        .addComponent(jTextField9)
                        .addComponent(jTextField8)
                        .addComponent(jTextField7)))
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 358, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1))
    );

    jButton3.setText("Exit");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField11.setText("jTextField11");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jTextField11)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addComponent(jTextField11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    System.exit(0);
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jTextField1.setText("");
    jTextField2.setText("");
    jTextField3.setText("");
    jTextField4.setText("");
    jTextField5.setText("");
    jTextField6.setText("");
    jTextField7.setText("");
    jTextField8.setText("");
    jTextField9.setText("");
    jTextField10.setText("");
    jTextField11.setText("");
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    System.out.println(randomInt);
    jTextField11.setText("field "+" selected");

    switch (randomInt)
    {
        case 0:
            jTextField11.setText("field  "+jTextField1.getText()+" selected");
            break;
            case 1:
            jTextField11.setText("field "+jTextField2.getText()+" selected");
            break;
            case 2:
            jTextField11.setText("field "+jTextField3.getText()+" selected");
            break;
            case 3:
            jTextField11.setText("field "+jTextField4.getText()+" selected");
            break;
            case 4:
           jTextField11.setText("field " +jTextField5.getText()+" selected");
            break;
            case 5:
            jTextField11.setText("field "+jTextField6.getText()+" selected");
            break;
            case 6:
           jTextField11.setText("field "+jTextField7.getText()+" selected");
            break;
            case 7:
            jTextField11.setText("field "+jTextField8.getText()+" selected");
            break;
            case 8:
           jTextField11.setText("field "+jTextField9.getText()+" selected");
            break;
            case 9:
            jTextField11.setText("field "+jTextField10.getText()+" selected");
            break;


    }
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Michelleschoices.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Michelleschoices.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Michelleschoices.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Michelleschoices.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Michelleschoices().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField10;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField11;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField8;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField9;
// End of variables declaration
 }
```

Comment: Thank you joey that was pretty much exactly what i was looking to do! Thank you for the quick replies and answer.

Comment: @user2238229 if the answer is ok for you, you can accept it by clicking on the blank check mark.

Comment: `JTextField[10] jTextFields; for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { jTextFields[i] = new javax.swing.JTextField(); }` Then to clear (button 1) you can just loop `for (JTextField field : jTextFields) { field.setText(""); }` and instead of a `switch` just generate the random int 0-9 and index directly into the array.

Comment: @StephenP Yeah thats a good idea :), may be OP just wants textfields by drag and drop